# Kind of confused on the push_front property. What would intList.push_front(2 * intList.back()) exactly do?

Tags: c++, iterator, linked-list

I have a linked list full of certain numbers called intList. What would

```
intList.push_front(2 * intList.back());
```

do to my list?

Answer (score 5):

It would prepend two times the value of the last element of the list at the front of the list, increasing the length of the list by one. This assumes that your list holds elements of a type that can be multiplied by an integer using `operator*`.

Note that the list cannot be empty. Calling `back()` on an empty list is undefined behaviour.

See relevant references [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_front) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/back).

For illustration purposes, consider a list containing

> 1, 2, 3, 4

The operation would modify the list such that it containg

> 8, 1, 2, 3, 4

where the front of the list is on the left.

Comment: so if the last number in the list was 10 then it would multiply that by 2 and then append it to the front of the list? Oh snap, I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @JesseAlford I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

It takes the last element from the list and adds twice of its value in front of the list.